# Update objects from an array in a MongoDB collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, express

I need to send an array of objects with respective ID's from client-side code via JSON to an API endpoint that is serve by ExpressJS.

Now I need to update existing DB objects with all the fields from the array of objects. I suppose a for..in loop doesn't look good in this case. Neither did I find a way to update multiple documents in one run.

I use [MongoJS library](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs) to work with MongoDB from NodeJS

Please advise.

Comment: in mongodb, update multiple documents can be done with multi:true

Answer (score 0):

may be

`db.mycollection.update({name:'some name'}, {$inc:{level:1}}, {multi:true}, function() {
    // the update is complete
});`

for **mongojs** library help you...

Thanks